# Converting indices in marching cubes to original x,y,z space - visualizing isosurface 3d skimage

Tags: python, scikit-image, marching-cubes, isosurface

I want to draw a volume in x1,x2,x3-space. The volume is an isocurve found by the marching cubes algorithm in skimage. The function generating the volume is `pdf_grid = f(x1,x2,x3)` and

---

I want to draw the volume where pdf = 60% max(pdf).

My issue is that the marching cubes algorithm generates vertices and faces, but how do I map those back to the x1, x2, x3-space?

My (rather limited) understanding of marching cubes is that "vertices" refer to the indices in the volume (pdf_grid in my case). If "vertices" contained only the exact indices in the grid this would have been easy, but "vertices" contains floats and not integers. It seems like marching cubes do some interpolation between grid points (according to https://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0405/shape/marching_cubes.html), so the question is then how to recover exactly the values of x1,x2,x3?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Make some random data
cov = np.array([[1, .2, -.5],
                [.2, 1.2, .1],
                [-.5, .1, .8]])
dist = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(mean = [1., 3., 2], cov = cov)
N = 500
x_samples = dist.rvs(size=N).T

#Create the kernel density estimator - approximation of a pdf
kernel = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(x_samples)
x_mean = x_samples.mean(axis=1)
#Find the mode
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda x: -kernel.logpdf(x),
                                 x_mean #x0, initial guess
                                 )
x_mode = res["x"]

num_el = 50 #number of elements in the grid
x_min = np.min(x_samples, axis = 1)
x_max = np.max(x_samples, axis = 1)
x1g, x2g, x3g = np.mgrid[x_min[0]:x_max[0]:num_el*1j,
                         x_min[1]:x_max[1]:num_el*1j,
                         x_min[2]:x_max[2]:num_el*1j
                         ]

pdf_grid = np.zeros(x1g.shape) #implicit function/grid for the marching cubes
for an in range(x1g.shape[0]):
    for b in range(x1g.shape[1]):
        for c in range(x1g.shape[2]):
            pdf_grid[a,b,c] = kernel(np.array([x1g[a,b,c],
                                      x2g[a,b,c],
                                      x3g[a,b,c]]
                                      ))

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from skimage import measure

iso_level = .6 #draw a volume which contains pdf_val(mode)*60%
verts, faces, normals, values = measure.marching_cubes(pdf_grid, kernel(x_mode)*iso_level)

#How to convert the figure back to x1,x2,x3 space? I just draw the output as it was done in the skimage example here https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.16.x/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-marching-cubes-py so you can see the volume

# Fancy indexing: `verts[faces]` to generate a collection of triangles
mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces], 
                        alpha = .5, 
                        label = f"KDE = {iso_level}"+r"$x_{mode}$",
                        linewidth = .1)
mesh.set_edgecolor('k')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

c1 = ax.add_collection3d(mesh)
c1._facecolors2d=c1._facecolor3d
c1._edgecolors2d=c1._edgecolor3d

#Plot the samples. Marching cubes volume does not capture these samples
pdf_val = kernel(x_samples) #get density value for each point (for color-coding)
x1, x2, x3 = x_samples
scatter_plot = ax.scatter(x1, x2, x3, c=pdf_val, alpha = .2, label = r" samples")
ax.scatter(x_mode[0], x_mode[1], x_mode[2], c = "r", alpha = .2, label = r"$x_{mode}$")

ax.set_xlabel(r"$x_1$")
ax.set_ylabel(r"$x_2$")
ax.set_zlabel(r"$x_3$")
# ax.set_box_aspect([np.ptp(i) for me in x_samples])  # equal aspect ratio

cbar = fig.color bar(scatter_plot, ax=ax)
cbar.set_label(r"$KDE(w) \approx pdf(w)$")
ax.legend()

#Make the axis limit so that the volume and samples are shown.
ax.set_xlim(- 5, np.max(verts, axis=0)[0] + 3)
ax.set_ylim(- 5, np.max(verts, axis=0)[1] + 3)
ax.set_zlim(- 5, np.max(verts, axis=0)[2] + 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late of an answer to help OP, but in case anyone else comes across this post looking for a solution to this problem, the issue stems from the marching cubes algorithm outputting the relevant vertices in array space. This space is defined by the number of elements per dimension of the mesh grid and the marching cubes algorithm does indeed do some interpolation in this space (explaining the presence of floats).

Anyways, in order to transform the vertices back into x1,x2,x3 space you just need to scale and shift them by the appropriate quantities. These quantities are defined by the range, number of elements of the mesh grid, and the minimum value in each dimension respectively. So using the variables defined in the OP, the following will provide the actual location of the vertices:

```
verts_actual = verts*((x_max-x_min)/pdf_grid.shape) + x_min
```

Comment: What are `x_max` and `x_min` in this case? There are three directions, `x1`, `x2`, `x3`. In my case I can plot with `verts, faces, normals, values = measure.marching_cubes(Ecd0, np.amin(Ecd0)*CA[8])` where `np.shape(Ecd0) = (280, 608, 480)` but `np.shape(verts) = (28206, 3)`.

Comment: x_max and x_min are the vectors of maximum and minimum values in each dimension. In other words:

x_max = (x1_max, x2_max, x3_max) & x_min = (x1_min, x2_min, x3_min)... 

Hope this helps!